# How do I use a type definition that is not exposed by the library but is implemented in the typing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm using TypeScript with Electron and I'd like to use the type definition for `WebContents`. The `WebContents` class is not exposed directly in the API, so this doesn't compile:

```
// I'd like to set the return type to WebContents, but TypeScript can't 
// find that type
import { webContents } from 'electron';
export function getWebContents(id: number) : WebContents {
  return webContents.getAllWebContents().filter(wc => wc.id === id).pop();
}
```

But I can see the interface defined in the typing file: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/00b54a3f25f111afd7a6b70b3b56091c5f434129/github-electron/github-electron.d.ts#L3454

How do I use that type without being able to directly import the `WebContents` class?

Versions and typings.json:

```
"electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.8"
"typescript": "^1.8.10"
"typings": "^1.3.2"
----
"globalDependencies": {
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160807145350",
    "github-electron": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/github-electron/github-electron.d.ts#00b54a3f25f111afd7a6b70b3b56091c5f434129"
  }
```

Comment: Your code should compile as is using the type definitions on DT, but if it doesn't I'd check that `typings` didn't mangle them in some unexpected way, and that they are actually being included in your project.

Comment: @VadimMacagon I verified that my typings file has the `WebContents` definition. Anything else I can do to check what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as most declaration files on DT, this one is a **global declaration file**. This means that you don't have to import anything, the type declarations are always present anywhere in your project. Eg. this:

```
// app.ts
let theWebContents: Electron.WebContents
```

should compile just fine.

Comment: Thanks -- I was missing the Electron namespace on it. Good to know all the top level declarations in the d.ts file are available globally :)